# Django_tables2 how to display nessary columns

Tags: python, django, django-filter, django-tables2

I am new in Django, how I can display nessary columns(id, name, birthdate)?
fisrt I try by this way but no effect:

"class ClothingColumn(tables.Column):defrender(self, record):returnstr(record.shirts + record.pants)"

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('full name', max_length=50)
    fname = models.CharField('family name', max_length=50)
    birthdate = models.DateField(null=True)
```

tables.py

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from .models import Person

class PersonTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        attrs = {'class': 'paleblue'}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django_tables2 import RequestConfig, SingleTableMixin
from .models import Person
from .tables import PersonTable

def people_listing(request):
    table = PersonTable(Person.objects.all())
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    table.paginate(page=request.GET.get("page", 1), per_page=1)
    return render(request, "tutorial/index.html", {"table": table})
```

index.html

```
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/screen.css' %}" />
    </head>
    <body>
         {% render_table table %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is django-filter's DateFromToRangeFilter what you're looking for? https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#datefromtorangefilter

Comment: Yes see DateTimeFromToRangeFilter, but do not know how to use it to views and template

Comment: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#the-view First, try the example provided in the docs. The documentation should be the first place to look for an answer. See also this link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you can help to make html template?

Comment: why there using url not re_path?

Comment: it don't work and give me an error: Person() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'

Comment: I don't think anyone can help you without seeing your code. You'd have to update your question. The django-filter documentation uses `url` and not `path` probably because they haven't updated it after Django 2.0 release ;)

Comment: Ok, I will update my question!